# Changing map's bounds and using the slider to change the data displayed without redrawing the map

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I'm working on a map that displays a prevalence per location. I've been able to display and filter the data as needed but when I zoom in/change the map's bounds and then use the slider, it seems evident that the map is being zoomed out to the default view and then redrawn and zoomed in. I've tried incorporating `leafletProxy` but haven't gotten it to fully work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
data <- data.frame(year = c(2007, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009), 
                   lat = c(33.54816, 34.26147, 34.97830, 44.33714, 42.15185), 
                   long = c(-79.04450, -85.174106, -83.45774, -89.74232, -85.42715), 
                   perc_pos = c(60, 30, 10, 20, 5))

cols <- c("#191970", "#fdae61", "#8b0000")

mypalette <- colorNumeric(palette = cols, domain = c(0,100), na.color = "transparent")

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"), 
  sliderInput("range", 
              label = "Select year/range",
               step = 1,
               min = 0, 
               max = 1, 
               value = c(0,1),
               animate = TRUE))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  map_df = reactive({
    data %>% 
      filter(between(year, input$range[1], input$range[2]))
      
  })
  updateSliderInput(session, "range",
                    min = min(data$year, na.rm = TRUE),
                    max = max(data$year, na.rm = TRUE),
                    value = c(min(data$year, na.rm = TRUE), max(data$year, na.rm = TRUE)))
  output$mymap = renderLeaflet(
    {
      leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.VoyagerLabelsUnder") %>%
        setView(lng=-90, lat=39, zoom = 4) %>%
        addLegend(data = map_df(), 
                  title = "positive (%
)",
                  pal = mypalette, 
                  values = c(0:100), 
                  opacity = 0.8) %>%
        addMiniMap(width = 150, height = 150)
        })
  
  observe({
    coords <- input$mymap_bounds
    if (!is.null(coords)){
      leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
        fitBounds(coords$west,
                   coords$south,
                   coords$east,
                   coords$north) %>%
        clearMarkers() %>%
        addCircles(data = map_df(),
                   radius = 100000,
                   color = ~mypalette(perc_pos),
                   fillColor = ~mypalette(perc_pos),
                   fillOpacity = 0.8,
                   stroke = FALSE,
                   highlightOptions = highlightOptions(sendToBack = TRUE,
                                                       fillOpacity = 0.5))
    }})
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```